# Inheritance of Parent Class values

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I would like to know which is the correct way to use parent class values inside a child class method.

This is a reproducible example:

```
class Human:
    numberOfEyes = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.man = None

    def createMan(self):
        self.man = Man()


class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        Human.__init__(self)
        # super(Man, self).__init__()

    def printNumberOfEyes(self):
        print("A man has {0} eyes".format(self.numberOfEyes))


def main():
    human = Human()
    human.createMan()

    human.man.printNumberOfEyes()

    human.numberOfEyes = 18

    human.man.printNumberOfEyes()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output in both case of `Human.__init__(self)` or `super(Man, self).__init__()`:

```
A man has 2 eyes
A man has 2 eyes
```

I would like to see this:

```
A man has 2 eyes
A man has 18 eyes
```

Comment: `human` is an instance of `Human`. `man` is an instance of `Man`. They both have their own sets of attributes. Setting `self.numberOfEyes` for `human` won't change it for `man`. What was the reasoning behind not doing this `human.man.numberOfEyes = 18`? I'm sorry if that comes off as rude, I'm just trying to see how you're thinking about the problem.

Comment: That being said.. the `createMan` method seems unnecessary. If you want an instance of `Man` you can just `man = Man()` within your `main` function. `man` will inherit `numberOfEyes` from `Human` as long as you call the `__init__` method from `Human`. The reason it doesn't just automatically run is because you override it in your `Man` class.

Comment: @Axe319 thanks for your reply. I don't use `human.man.numberOfEyes = 18` because in the original code `numberOfEyes` changes its value on human instance and I want to use the updated value on man instance. Like a C/C++ pointer

Comment: There are some workarounds but it seems like what you want is a shared state across instances. To do that you would want to use a class attribute and not an instance attribute.

Comment: Could you please post a working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is shared state across instances. You can achieve this with a class attribute.

```
class Human:
    # placing an attribute directly inside the class
    # makes it a class attribute and can be referenced 
    # across instances
    # the underscore here is a way of implying it's private
    # and shouldn't be accessed from outside the class
    _numberOfEyes = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.man = None

    def createMan(self):
        self.man = Man()
    
    # this is a property decorator
    # when you make something a property
    # Whenever you try to access self.numberOfEyes
    # as an attribute it calls this method and returns
    # whatever you return
    @property
    def numberOfEyes(self):
        # and this is how you reference a class attribute
        return Human._numberOfEyes

    # this is the setter for self.numberOfEyes
    # it does the exact thing a property does except
    # it sets it
    @numberOfEyes.setter
    def numberOfEyes(self, val):
        Human._numberOfEyes = val


class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        # I prefer super here since you don't need to
        # explicitly name the parent class
        # the arguments for super can be removed in python 3
        super().__init__()

    def printNumberOfEyes(self):
        print("A man has {0} eyes".format(self.numberOfEyes))


def main():
    human = Human()
    human.createMan()

    human.man.printNumberOfEyes()

    human.numberOfEyes = 18

    human.man.printNumberOfEyes()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That being said. Python has a few naming conventions you'll come across if you plan on sharing your code. One of those is the use of `snake_case` over `camelCase` for identifiers.

Comment: Many thanks. Such a simple task in Python is over complicated. If OOP is the target Python is a crap...